# (AWS) Ubuntu Jenkins pipeline doesn't receive webhook call

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jenkins, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to set up a simple jenkins pipeline that uses SCM polling to receive a POST request from github via a webhook and build the repo accordingly. At the moment, the webhook request is made, but jenkins doesn't seem to acknowledge it. I've checked the security groups on AWS, and don't think they're the problem:

```
HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0
HTTP TCP 80 ::/0
Custom TCP Rule TCP 8080 0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule TCP 8080 ::/0
SSH TCP 22 0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS TCP 443 ::/0
```

I've also checked the URL the webhook is pointing to in github when github push requests are made:

```
http://{ec2_instance}:8080/github-webhook/
```

using:

`x-www-form-urlencoded`

But also to no avail, although the requests are made in the history. If I manually build, it works fine, however it doesn't seem to recognise the webhook polls. I'm a little stumped, have I missed part of the process? Or is there some reason that AWS may have blocked the post requests?

If i've missed any crucial information, please feel free to ask.

Thanks

EDIT: Looked through the Jenkins logs, when I redeliver to the webhook, jenkins gives a:

```
May 18, 2017 9:36:32 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.subscriber.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber onEvent
INFO: Received PushEvent for https://github.com/CJWaszczuk/Banking-API from 192.30.252.42 ⇒ http://ec2-52-213-234-202.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/github-webhook/
May 18, 2017 9:36:32 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.PushGHEventSubscriber onEvent
INFO: Received PUSH for https://github.com/CJWaszczuk/Banking-API from 192.30.252.42 ⇒ http://ec2-52-213-234-202.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/github-webhook/
```

Comment: Are you using a hardened AMI? Do you see anything in the Jenkins logs?

Comment: See edit in post.

Comment: Looks like this was resolved in February. What version of Jenkins are you running? https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41820